# Access HTML TextField Components with Java/C Through Browser

Tags: java, c++, html

I would like to know if it is possible to access existing HTML components (text field, Button etc.) from Facebook, Twitter and so on, with a Java or C/C++ program. The algorithm should execute as follows:

1. Import HTML components
2. Fill in username and pw in appropriate text field.
3. Log in.

My goal is to open up a browser and use universal login data to log into social networks with a button click. Is there a specific technology to use? How do I import the HTML site components, write data to it and send it as a regular HTML request (login)? I was looking for a personal projects and came up with this idea. I appreciate your time and effort. Thanks

-Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I remember there is a COM object from Miscrosoft ( a really commonplace one ) that offers services of a browser window.

Take a look at `IWebBrowser2::Navigate2` and `CHtmlView::Navigate2` 
I remember Navigate2 was the function to call to ask the control to connect to an URL.